# Riot selector not working

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm trying to do a very basic Riot test example. My HTML is (includes) as follows:

```
<recommendation></recommendation>
<recommendation></recommendation>
<recommendation></recommendation>
<recommendation></recommendation>
<recommendation></recommendation>

<script type="riot/tag">
<recommendation>
  <h3>Hey, here's a recommendation</h3>
</recomendation>
</script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/riot/riot/master/riot%2Bcompiler.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var tags = riot.mount('*');
  console.log('tags', tags);
</script>
```

The output of the `console.log` is just `tags []`. From what I understand, it should get all of the `<recommendation>` tags.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6s2tab7a/

Comment: Its trying to parse the `<script type="riot/tag">` content as javascript content. Try to put the `<recommendation>` template in an external file.

Comment: Hmm, the fiddle doesn't seem to be working for me, either. Is it working for you? Due to the constraints of the rest of my application, I would really rather not put it in an external file.

Comment: Its not running for me either, but its easier for people to debug actual running code. Just put it there for reference. :)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't work because you have wrongly closed your tag </recomendation> => </recommendation>

Comment: @GianlucaGuarini man I feel like an idiot. Thank you!

Comment: @GianlucaGuarini if you want to submit that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have wrongly closed your tag `</recomendation> => </recommendation>`

This kind of errors could be easily checked by using our cli `riot --check component.tag` or just using a good IDE

Comment: Hey don't insult vim (I just haven't gotten the right plugins yet ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var tags = riot.mount('recommendation');
```

Or:

```
    while(var tags = riot.mount('recommendation'))
{
  console.log('tags', tags);
}
```

Or:

```
 for(var i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
  console.log('tags', riot.mount('recommendation'));
}
```

Comment: No dice. I assume you meant putting the `rawgit` script first, but I also tried the ordering `rawgit` => `tag definition` => `mount code` => `mount point` but that didn't work either. =/

Comment: Oh sorry, I completely said nothing.I though this was normal javascript.

Comment: Sorry if i couldn't help

Comment: I'm afraid not. :/ I'm going to try out Vuejs.